# In Laravel, why the controller can get the specific model object by only receiving an id parameter

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    return view('post.show',['post'=>$post]);
}
```

I have the code above in PostController

```
<a href="{{ route('post.show',$post->id) }}">{{ $post->title }}</a>
```

and the code above in the blade view  only transfer post_id from a specific Post object to the PostController@show function, but the show function can use the specific Post object directly without adding like `$post = Post::find($id)`. I wanna know which feature Laravel uses to turn id to a Post object. Is it Contract or Service Container ?

Answer (score 0):

They are [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-model-binding) and [Dependency Injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers).